# DBeaver - Cannot connect to pgsql via SSH tunnel

Tags: dbeaver, ssh-tunnel

I tried to connect remote pgsql server via SSH tunnel, but I have got EOFException.

[image]

I have no idea what should be wrong.

This is my connection settings:
[image]

SSH configuration is OK
[image]

This is the SSH settings:
[image]